# How to get all but the last n values of iterable

Tags: python, generator, iterable

```
def drop(iterable, n):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    iter_list = []
    
    try:
        while True:
            it = next(iterator)
            if len(iter_list) <= n:
                iter_list.append(it)
                yield it
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

I'm suppose to produce all values from the iterable except for the last n values. Right now, I have it so that it produces at most n values. How do I do it so that it's the other way around? I'd like to keep the same structure if I can.

I'm not allowed to count the number of values the iterable produces. I also can't use itertools or call len, index, slice, etc on the iterable.

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: Are you suggesting that `len(iter_list)` does not count the number of values the iterable produces?

Comment: It depends on if the length of the iterable is deterministic, if the iterable has an unknown length there is no option apart from consuming it whole then dropping the last n items.

Comment: This is what collections.dequeue is for!  Read the first n elements into the queue.  As the user asks for a new one, add an element to the end and remove an element from the front and return it to them.

Comment: @khelwood nope, but you do need at least `n` space, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import deque

def drop(it, n):
    queue = deque()
    for _ in range(n):
      queue.append(next(it))
    while True:
      # If next(it) throws a StopIteration, we need a little bit more
      # code here to indicate this iterable if finished.
      queue.append(next(it))
      yield queue.popleft()
```

I probably need to add a couple of try/except StopIteration to get it running perfectly, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Here is a complete version: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/550a8daf79a9813ff472b0d22290525f feel free to fill yours in.

Comment: You're saying you can't find it?  Or you're not allowed to use it?  Just use a list instead (`queue = []`) and replace `queue.popleft()` with `queue.pop(0)`.  Popping the left-most element off a list is inefficient if the list is long, but when you're prohibited from using the best tool. .  .

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options here first is to generate the whole iterable and drop the last n, and in the while loop you return every value from the start or the more clever way of using a buffer of n values. Just a slight modification to your code will do the trick

```
def drop(iterable, n):
   iterator = iter(iterable)
   iter_list = []

   try:
        while True:
            it = next(iterator)
            iter_list.append(it)
            if len(iter_list) > n:
                element = iter_list.pop(0)
                yield element
   except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Here every new element is appended in the while loop and the condition to yield elements runs after the first n elements are generated. Then the first generated element is yielded, and so on with n elements generated always. When the iterator has no more to give the exception is raised and the while loop stops withholding the last n elements that are never returned

Comment: I forgot to mention but I'm not allowed to append all the values of the iterable to a list.

Comment: with this method you don't append all of them only n when a new comes the old one is returned

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. It seemed like the iter_list.append(it) was appending every value of the iterable to iter_list before comparing its list length with n

Comment: no just the first n, after that it deletes a value form the list and adds a new one. Also might i suggest that in your original code you do not need to append the values to a list just keep a counter to compare instead of len of the list

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: well add variable `counter = 0` outside of the loop, replace the `if len(iter_list) > n:` with `if counter > n:` and instead of `iter_list.append(itt)` just do `counter += 1` that's all. Also i am pretty sure you might have a bug cause when i try it instead of returning only n elements it returns n+1 elements. you might want to change the if condition from <= to <